# canonical-live patch status error executing status: live patch error: snappy kernel-module-control interface not connected

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Stderr: error executing config: livepatchd error: snappy kernel-module-control interface not connected

how do I correct this?

Comment: Live Patch is off topic for this site and you need to address any issues with it to Canonical directly. Sorry. A ways down the page you will see how to report issues. https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/faq

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1438072/edit) to specify your release of Ubuntu. This issue occurs most commonly when folks move away from an LTS release (like from 22.04 LTS to 22.10). LivePatch is LTS-only.

Comment: @David: Where did you get the information that Livepatch is off-topic on AU? A search on AU shows 150 questions about Livepatch, many with accepted answers.